# Do Java Library has abstract classes ??

Tags: java, abstract-class, native

Recently I had an interview in java and the interviewer asked me about the `abstract classes`given by java by default, is there any?

Thinking about this I couldn't figure out the answer because since we cannot instantiate an `abstract class` and while doing code in `java` we mostly make an object of library classes given by java so that means it is not an `abstract class`. So can someone tell me is there any `java` library given `abstract class` because as I query on web the links given mostly about defining an `abstract class` or use of `abstract class..`

Thank you..

Comment: `AbstractList`, `AbstractCollection` there are many

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP needs to have a minimal understanding of question topic.  This could be resolved by a basic tutorial or introductory guide.

Answer (score 6):

The Collections API has a few:

- AbstractCollection
- AbstractList
- AbstractQueue
- AbstractDeque
- AbstractSet
- AbstractMap

To name a few

Answer (score 5):

Examples available in the JDK:

- [java.io.InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)
- [java.io.OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html)
- [java.io.Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html)
- [java.io.Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html)
- [java.lang.Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)